# google maps API v3 put draggable maker

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, draggable, point

this my code,

```
function initialize() {
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
    var city = 'battaramulla';
    var center = '';
    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
    map.setUIToDefault();

    var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
    geocoder.getLatLng(city, function (point) {
      if (!point) {
        alert(city+" not found :-(");
      } else {
            alert(city+" "+point+" found :-)");
            map.setCenter(point, 8);
      }
    });
}
}
```

I want to add drggable maker to this **city(point)**. Please help me. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this complete example...

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">`enter code here`
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

function geocodePosition(pos) {
  geocoder.geocode({
    latLng: pos
  }, function(responses) {
    if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
      updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
    } else {
      updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
    }
  });
}

function updateMarkerStatus(str) {
  document.getElementById('markerStatus').innerHTML = str;
}

function updateMarkerPosition(latLng) {
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = [
    latLng.lat(),
    latLng.lng()
  ].join(', ');
}

function updateMarkerAddress(str) {
  document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = str;
}

function initialize() {
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    title: 'Point A',
    map: map,
    draggable: true
  });

  // Update current position info.
  updateMarkerPosition(latLng);
  geocodePosition(latLng);

  // Add dragging event listeners.
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function() {
    updateMarkerAddress('Dragging...');
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
    updateMarkerStatus('Dragging...');
    updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
    updateMarkerStatus('Drag ended');
    geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
  });
}

// Onload handler to fire off the app.
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <style>
  #mapCanvas {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    float: left;
  }
  #infoPanel {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
  #infoPanel div {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  </style>

  <div id="mapCanvas"></div>
  <div id="infoPanel">
    <b>Marker status:</b>
    <div id="markerStatus"><i>Click and drag the marker.</i></div>
    <b>Current position:</b>
    <div id="info"></div>
    <b>Closest matching address:</b>
    <div id="address"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In here how to set my predefine city as point instead of latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 0):

Use geocoder to find the closest address.

```
function geocodePosition(pos) {
  geocoder.geocode({
    latLng: pos
  }, function(responses) {
    if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
      updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
    } else {
      updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
    }
  });
}
```